# sql to inset into a table with select query from table having multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to figure out the right way to write sql to insert values from a table, where I need to pick Ids from anotehr table.

eg:

```
INSERT INTO `ts`.`priorityraw`
(`clientid`,`priorityid`,`typeid`)
VALUES
('AA',1,202),
('AA',1,203),
('AA',1,206),
('AA',1,210),
('AA',1,213);
```

Here clientId and priority is constant. typeid i need to pick from another table.
How can i modify above query to the following format? it gives issue with

> as

syntx

```
 INSERT INTO `ts`.`priorityraw`
    (`clientid`,`priorityid`,`typeid`)
SELECT 'as01' AS `clientid`, '1' AS `priorityid`,
  id AS `typeid`
FROM
    ts.types
ORDER BY
   id;
```

Comment: Just remove that `Alias` and try it

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy i get further issue says, it is not valid input

Comment: Remove the `AS` portion. You don't need it because you're not displaying the column or referencing it anywhere else. You also can't use the `ORDER BY`, because there's no purpose in sorting the data when inserting it into another table; you would sort it when you're SELECTing from that destination table later. A good SQL tutorial would help with these sorts of questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
 INSERT INTO `ts`.`priorityraw`
    (`clientid`,`priorityid`,`typeid`)
SELECT 'as01', 1,
  id 
FROM
    ts.types
ORDER BY
   id;
```

Comment: Should explain reason for answer.